# How to find a minimal set of keys?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I have a set of keys *K* and a finite set *S* ⊂ *K* <sup>*n*</sup> of *n*-tuples of keys. Is there an efficient algorithm to find a bijective mapping *f* : *S* ↦ *S'* where *S'* ⊂ *K* <sup>*k*</sup> with *k* < *n* minimal that strips some of the keys, leaving the others untouched?

Comment: I assume `|S|=|S'|`, otherwise there is no such bijection, but that's a hard constraint on `S'`. Is `S'` given, or you can "choose" that subset?

Comment: @amit Observe that S is a subset of K^n, it may contain just one element. The goal is to find a mapping that discards some of the keys such that you can still distinguish all elements of S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this is NP-complete.

It is equivalent to [set cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

Each of your keys allows you to distinguish certain pairs of elements (i.e. a set of edges).  Your task is to select the smallest number of keys that allows you to distinguish every element - i.e. the smallest number of sets of edges that allows you to cover every edge.

However, the wiki page shows an approximate solution based on integer programming that may give a useful solution in practice.

### Sketch of Proof

Suppose we have a generic set cover problem:

```
A,B,C
C,D
A,B,D
```

where we need to find the smallest number of these sets to cover every element A,B,C,D.

We construct a tuple for each letter A,B,C,D.

The tuple has a unique number in position i if and only if set i contains the letter.  Otherwise, they contain 0.

There is also a zero tuple.

This means that the tuples would look like:

```
(0,0,0)  The zero tuple
(1,0,2)  The tuple for A (in sets 1 and 3)
(3,0,4)  The tuple for B (in sets 1 and 3)
(5,6,0)  The tuple for C (in sets 1 and 2)
(0,7,8)  The tuple for D (in sets 2 and 3)
```

If you could solve your problem efficiently, you would then be able to use this mapping to solve set cover efficiently.

Comment: I understand your reasoning. Thank you for taking the time to write up this sketch of proof!